PyCharm doesn't print but works fine in PyCharm Community
I am encountering an issue when using PyCharm Professional with an educational license. My program doesn't produce any output, even though the same code works fine in PyCharm Community Edition.
For example, when I run a simple program like this:

PyCharm Professional does not print "Hello, World!" as expected. Additionally, for programs that require input, it seems like PyCharm Pro enters an infinite input loop and no output is displayed.
I have already checked the Python interpreter configuration in both editions, and they are the same. I also tried reinstalling PyCharm Professional, but the issue persists.

Please add more detail about your environment (eg python interperter settings in PyCharm).

I would guess your Python interpreter, C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\python.exe, is misbehaving.
This is not about PyCharm per se, but the interpreter you're using there. Try clicking on the "C:\Users\PC\anaconda3" status bar item to switch to another interpreter if you have one (and if you don't, you can get a fresh Python from https://www.python.org/downloads/ – PyCharm should pick up the installation then as an interpreter option).
